# insert data from one mysql table to another

Tags: sql

i am trying to run this SQL query to copy data from one table to another but it shows zero rows returned:

```
INSERT INTO ticket_updates 
VALUES
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM ticket_updates2 
  WHERE sequence = '4715'
)
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting and marking answers (checking the checkmark below the votes) on the answers to your questions that are helpful.  It helps both of us earn those meaningless internet points. :)  If there is more that I can clarify, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put a select statement into a values method.

Your syntax should look like this:

```
INSERT into ticket_updates(all,my,columns)
select all,my,columns from ticket_updates2 where sequence = '4715'
```